# Proof that Piecewise function is Rienmann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Let *f* : [0,1] → R be a function defined by:

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if 0 ≤ x < 1} \\
1, & \text{if x = 1}
\end{cases}

Proof *f* is Riemann integrable on [0,1] using L(Pn) and U(Pn)

Now I try and attempts to show The suprema of L(Pn) is equal to the infimum of U(Pn).
I found U(P) to be 1/n
and L(P) = 0 so by letting n → ∞ we can deduce L = U. Is this approach i took correct?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.